# Нужен ремонт .htaccess

Tags: веб-программирование, .htaccess, apache

Всем доброго времени суток!
Есть 3 задачи, которые я хочу реализовать при помощи файла .htaccess:

1. Работать только с протоколом `https`
2. Создать 301-редирект с `https://www.mysite.com` на `https://mysite.com`
3. Все запросы переадресовать на файл `index.php`

Лучшая моя версия .htaccess, спустя 2х суток гуглежа, выглядит вот так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

*Информация для профессионалов в этом вопросе:
Ваше потраченное время, готов компенсировать своим, поработав на Вас.*
**Буду благодарен любым советам!**